# When trying to open the .xlsx file created by selenium, getting a message stating that the file is corrupted

Tags: java, selenium

I created an .xlsx file using selenium through File "fil.createNewFile()", the file got created in the location but when i try to open the file i am getting a message "Excel cannot open the file 'Example.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid....". Why is this happening. Please guide me to over come this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying something like:

```
File fil = new File("Example.xlsx");
fil.createNewFile();
```

Well, it this is your case you're creating a file with xlsx extension, but it's not truly a Excel file (it's empty). If you try to create a new file using Excel or File Explorer, you can see that a new fresh xlsx file weight about 10kb. If you need to create a Excel file you need to use Apache POI, or another library.

You need to add a sheet at least:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Example.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

PS: I use poi-ooxml, since you use a xlsx file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is my code

File fi = new File(D:\\Example.xlsx);
fi.createNewFile();

Its is creating a file in D location with name "Example.xlsx" but when trying to open it, it is saying the file might be corrupted or the extension might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What eltabo mentioned is correct. Below is a code sample from Apache POI which will create a blank excel file.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: The file you are creating is not a excel file, just giving a file a extention does not mean its a type of that file, for example you can also create a "new.jpg" file same way, that does not mean it will become a image. Excel is not a simple file it has its own structure, Java "File" can not create it, for creating a excel file you need a library named Apache POI. Above is the shown code that will work.

Comment: File fi = new File("D:\\Selenium\\Excel\\Example.xlsx");
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fi);
Workbook w = WorkbookFactory.create(fi);
w.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue("PASSPASS");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fi);
w.write(fos);
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Hi paul, I have pasted my code above, in that "Example.xlsx" is already existing file and i am trying to write on it, i am getting null pointer exception.

Thank you once again

Comment: I tried this as well but still getting nullpointerexception

File fi = new File("D:\\Selenium\\Excel\\Example.xlsx");
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fi);
XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFCell cell=w.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);
//System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
cell.setCellValue("PASSPASS");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fi);
w.write(fos);
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}  catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Please refer this url. And try the examples. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/